# R - Grouping values within a df

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I have a df in which each entry has an assigned grouped ID, like:

```
id_person income id_family
001       100    A1
002       120    B2
003       100    B5
004       220    A1
005       300    A2
```

And now I need to assign a new variable for each id_person, summing up the variable `income` of all entries with the same `id_family`. Such as:

```
id_person income id_family family_income
001       100    A1        220
002       120    B2        120
003       100    B5        400
004       220    A1        220
005       300    B5        400
```

I do not wish to create a new `grouped_df`, neither do I need to see this variable summarized for now.

How can I give this command using R?

Comment: Should that second A1 in your dataset be 220? Instead of 230? I am struggling to understand where the values come from for `family_income`

Comment: Also, `id_family` seems weird too.

Comment: Used letters in id_family to make it a quick example, visually different from id_person. Sorry about the 230.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using data in a data.table, we can perform operations on variables by a grouping variable (in `by=`), then assign that back to the data using the data.table assignment operator `:=`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, "family_income" := sum(income), by = id_family]
```

---

The data.table data structure is a pumped up version of the R data.frame, giving added functionality and efficiency gains. If `DT` is your data.table, `DT[i, j, by]` is the notation showing how we can use `i` to sort or subset data, `j` for selecting or computing on variables, and `by` to perfrom `j`-operations on groups. For example, for cars with over 100 horsepower, what is the mean fuel efficiency for automatic (0) and manual (1) cars?

```
dtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
dtcars[hp>100, mean(mpg), by=am]
```

Returns:

```
> dtcars[hp>100, mean(mpg), by=am]
   am       V1
1:  1 20.61429
2:  0 16.06875
```

Comment: Great solution indeed! Didn't know the `by` option.

Comment: Why can't I see the vector `family_income` when I use the `View()` function though?

Comment: Did you use `:=` or just `=`?

Comment: Also what happens whe  you execute the name of the data table in the console - does it return anything?

Answer (score 1):

You may try

## Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "id_person income id_family
001       100    A1
002       120    B2
003       100    B5
004       220    A1
005       300    B5", header = T)

  id_person income id_family
1         1    100        A1
2         2    120        B2
3         3    100        B5
4         4    220        A1
5         5    300        B5
```

## Code

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id_family) %>%
  mutate(family_income = sum(income)) %>%
  ungroup
    
  id_person income id_family family_income
      <int>  <int> <chr>             <int>
1         1    100 A1                  320
2         2    120 B2                  120
3         3    100 B5                  400
4         4    220 A1                  320
5         5    300 B5                  400
```

Comment: I can't try it myself now: working + studying + parenting is really hard. But I am confident this answer will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id_family) %>% 
  summarise(Total = sum(income, na.rm = TRUE))
```

or the `across()` function could be used:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id_family) %>%
  summarise(across(income, sum))
```